# SqlDataReader are these two the same Which one is faster

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sqldatareader, sqlxml

I am working with SqlXml and the stored procedure that returns a xml rather than raw data. How does one actually read the data when returned is a xml and does not know about the column names. I used the below versions and have heard getting data from SqlDataReader through ordinal is faster than through column name. Please advice on which is best and with a valid reason or proof

1. `sqlDataReaderInstance.GetString(0);`
2. `sqlDataReaderInstance[0];`

Comment: @Kangkan i believe method too relies on the indexer, correct me if wrong!

Comment: Related: [datareader-hardcode-ordinals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882280/datareader-hardcode-ordinals)

Comment: This link: http://blog.maskalik.com/ado-net/data-reader-performance-optimizations/ says "reader.GetString(0)" will be faster. Though I'm skeptical of his timings I think he has a point overall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> and have heard getting data from SqlDataReader through ordinal is faster than through column name

Both your examples are getting data through the index (ordinal), not the column name:

Getting data through the column name:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    ...
    var value = reader["MyColumnName"];
    ...
}
```

is potentially slower than getting data through the index:

```
int myColumnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("MyColumnName");
while(reader.Read())
{
    ...
    var value = reader[myColumnIndex];
    ...
}
```

because the first example must repeatedly find the index corresponding to "MyColumnName".  If you have a very large number of rows, the difference might even be noticeable.

In most situations the difference won't be noticeable, so favour readability.

**UPDATE**

If you are really concerned about performance, an alternative to using ordinals is to use the [DbEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbenumerator.aspx) class as follows:

```
foreach(IDataRecord record in new DbEnumerator(reader))
{
    ...
    var value = record["MyColumnName"];
    ...
}
```

The `DbEnumerator` class reads the schema once, and maintains an internal HashTable that maps column names to ordinals, which can improve performance.

Comment: Joe, I believe all the major ADO.NET connectors do maintain an internal hashtable for column name to ordinal mapping. I have confirmed for SQLite and MySQL. So "record["string"]" is fairly efficient anyway (I mean even without DbEnumerator class). But I do think foreach-ing the reader like you did does have its benefits.

Comment: using the updated solution, I get the following error: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type `System.Data.Common.DbEnumerator' because it does not contain a definition for `GetEnumerator' or is inaccessible

Answer (score 4):

Compared to the speed of getting data from disk both will be effectively as fast as each other.

The two calls aren't equivalent: the version with an indexer returns an object, whereas `GetString()` converts the object to a string, throwing an exception if this isn't possible (i.e. the column is `DBNull`).

So although `GetString()` might be slightly slower, you'll be casting to a string anyway when you use it.

Given all the above I'd use `GetString()`.

Comment: +1 @Jeremy i would mark this answer if you provided some kind of profile,proof

Answer (score 1):

`Indexer` method is faster because it returns data in [native format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) and uses ordinal.

Have a look at these threads:

1. [Maximize Performance with SqlDataReader](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2006/08/09/maximize-performance-with-sqldatareader.aspx)
2. [.NET SqlDataReader Item[] vs. GetString(GetOrdinal())?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020117/net-sqldatareader-item-vs-getstringgetordinal)

Comment: does this mean i could also do `instance.Item[0]` ?