# What is the advantage of using typed accessors when accessing database column data instead of casting in ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Suppose I'm accessing a column of my database.

Is there any difference between doing this:

```
string userName = (string)reader[0];
```

and this?

```
string userName = reader.GetString(0);
```

MSDN says:

> When accessing column data use the typed accessors like GetString, GetInt32, and so on. This saves you the processing required to cast the Object returned from GetValue as a particular type.

It's a bad thing explicit casting??

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831574/sqldatareader-are-these-two-the-same-which-one-is-faster?lq=1

Comment: There's no difference mostly. Mind you depending on ADO.NET connector's implementation this can vary from database to database, but largely there's no difference from my experience. This link: http://blog.maskalik.com/ado-net/data-reader-performance-optimizations/ says typed accessor is faster. Though I'm skeptical of his timings I think he has a point overall.