# DataReader, retrieve data by column

Tags: asp.net, datareader, advantage-database-server

I want to retrieve data by column from DataReader.

Now I'm using like this,

```
AdsCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT a,b,c,d FROM testTable";
AdsDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

reader.Read();
string columnA = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(); // I want to use column name instead of index number
```

is there any way to get data by column name? like

```
string columnB = reader["B"].getValue();
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is a post asking a [related question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882280/datareader-hardcode-ordinals).  I posted some numbers comparing the two access methods if you are curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
string columnA = Convert.ToString(reader["B"]);
```